# Allot space to individual registered user

Tags: users, 7

I have a drupal site with many users.

How to add space to individual registered users in drupal site? Each user can be alloted a maximum space of 500MB for all his events, messages, videos and hotlist. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2):

A disc quota is one thing but also checking user-content in the db could be tricky :-). Never done something like this but here's what I would try:

- use [file_save_upload()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_save_upload/6) to validate the upload. Part of the validation should be
- the use of [file_validate_size()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_validate_size/6) and
- [file_space_used()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_space_used/6) to check the used space.

But as I said that checks only stuff inside the `files` table. No other content (text inside fields, cached content, thumbnails...) will be handled.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to measure text in MB's for this. You better have a number of limitations that you check separately (like 200MB files, 100 events, 20 videos, ...)

Comment: I agree with @berdir, you'd be (infinitely) better designing this around a system of individual limits per content/media type.

Comment: Yea, I think so, too. Question is, what is the reason behind the quota?

Comment: Thanks nonxenz and I have one doubt, Is it possible to allocate space to indevidual user in drupal site

Comment: check out the [file_space_used()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_space_used/6) link again. It says: "Determine total disk space used by a single user or the whole filesystem." But as I said before, it just checks the size of files registered inside the `files` table.

Comment: Hai nonsenz, Very thanks for your help and I want to restrict the "filedepot" module uploading file sizes basing on registered users. Please help me how to do?

Comment: I don't know the [filedepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot) module. inspecting it's .install file I 'm still nor sure if it stores size-info that is not already in the `files` table (but there *is* a size field). If it stores it's own information about files, you should rewrite the `file_space_used()` to check all the relevant fieldepot tables. But this really depends on how the module works and how you want to have your quota work (counting revisions, versions, ...).